# Are multiple pop-under advertisements from different ad networks possible to use on a single site?

Tags: advertising, monetize, money

I was wondering is it possible to place multiple pop-under adverts on the same website?

I am currently using Popcash for a single popunder which works fine and pays a small amount per day but i wanted to multiple that by maybe 2-3 pop-unders to launch on the page.  I know they are not very visitor friendly but it is mostly one time visitors and I want to monetize the traffic.

Has anyone else tried this?

Comment: They go way beyond user friendly - they just plain p1$$ people off! If you were to do this when I visit, it would be the last you would see of me. As well, Google is targeting sites with various pop-up schemes so I would HIGHLY recommend against using any ads of this type from here on out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...is it possible to place multiple pop-under adverts on the same website?

Possible? Yes. But Highly not recommended, especially if on the same page.

> I am currently using Popcash for a single pop-under which works fine and pays a small amount per day.

If the quality of ads are poor and/or your visitors have no interest in them, then you can expect low money.

> ...but i wanted to multiply that by maybe 2-3 pop-unders to launch on the page.

Now you're asking for visitor's computers to work twice as hard now. I feel sorry for any computer that has to go through what this computer went through:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ILxzRz-sGA

> I know they are not very visitor friendly but it is mostly one time visitors and I want to monetize the traffic.

Its worse than unfriendly. The more pop-unders or even pop-ups you have for a site, the worse it gets because they have to be closed down. (which is an extra unfriendly step on the user's end)

> Has anyone else tried this?

I'm sure too many people have. If you want advertising, try to make it the least intrusive. That means a small ad in the page that can be scrolled away from view.

Comment: Thanks for the info, would multiple CPM / PPV ads be reccomended if you cant use Adsense?

Comment: I wouldn't go with more than one ad personally.

Comment: What a crazy link/video!!

Answer (score 3):

**It would depend entirely on the ad networks themselves.** They may have restrictions against this very behavior in their terms of service. Also the scripts they use to load the ads could very well conflict with each other. You would simply have to try and see what happens.

Also - bad idea from a user's point of view. At best the user runs away, at worst you get flagged as a spam/adware site and blocked.